# Indexing by id and index

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I've a lot of objects with IDs, location and some visual properties.

I've breaking those objects to simple arrays (`Float32Array`) in order to upload them to the GPU.

So my arrays look like this

My vertex array [x,y]: `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]`
The data is in couples, means that the first and second are x&y of the first object, and the 3rd and 4th to the second object and so on...

In order to allow delete of objects, I need to map somehow my objects to index.

**1st :** I'm saving for each object its index - so I've ID to index mapping.

My mapping object look like this: `{ "id1": 0, "id2": 2, "id3":4, "id4":6 }`

The problem is after the first delete - all the indices after it are updated.
For example: I delete `id2`. So I find the index of it which is `2` and remove 2 items x&y. The array look like this now: `[1,1,3,3,4,4]`
My mapping of `id3` and `id4` are wrong now.

It is OK when we have 4 objects, but my arrays are very big, 500K and more...
And updating after every delete the indices of the objects which are after in the array is causing me very bad performances.

**2nd:**
I've tried also mapping it differently... As array : `[{id:"id1"}, {id:"id2"}..]`
This way before the delete, I need to find which index it is by its ID (getting very bad when deleting the lasts objects). But not updating it after delete.

Both ways are not good for me from performance point of view.

**-- EDIT --**

This is the solution that i'm using so far that gives me the best performance at the moment.

Every Object that being added creates ids for each letter it contains. and it gets the first letter id and the count of letters it created.

In the following example there are 3 objects with different amount of letters.

[image]

The objects are getting the ids of the first letter and the length.

In order to delete object B i'm running over my ids list and finding the id of B (which is 4) and i've found it at index 3. 
means that it's starting in my flat array at index  3 * 2(x,y) = 6. In order to delete it i would delete the length saved in the object. in this case 10 * 2(x,y) = 20 cells in the flat array. In addition i would delete 10 (the length) cells in the ids list. after delete the lists look like this

[image]

This is the fastest way I've found in order to delete over and over objects.

After clients complains that this is too slow, I've started to collect objects to delete and delete them all together - which mean - server is updating my clients objects - He running and deleting object by object in a loop - instead of deleting the objects immediately from the arrays i'm collecting them, and running once over my Ids list and finding all the ids indices - sorting them and deleting accordingly all together.

But this cause some other problems that i'm always finding some workaround.

Can't say that i'm happy with that.

**-- END EDIT --**

Any suggestions for better mapping?

Comment: Would be setting the value of an object to `undefined` be an option over removing it from the array?

Comment: *I've breaking those objects to simple arrays...My vertex array [x,y]: `[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]` the data is in couples* Is there any reason this needs to be in this format? This seems to be the root of your issue. Why don't you just store an array of objects `[{x:1, y:1}, {x:2:y:2},...]` this would simplify your problem considerably.

Comment: Not allowed, cause this data is being uploaded to the GPU and its need then to handle it. Don't forget, or maybe i didn't mention that adding objects are also taking places. so your way my array will grow and grow. One more thing, the array of vertex needs to be aligned with the others visual arrays. For ex. if vertex are [x,y,x,y,x,y] for 3 objects. colors will be [r,g,b,r,g,b,r,g,b] also for the same objects order.

Comment: Sadly @Liam this is the way of working with webgl/opengl with the graphic cards. Simplifying your data into arrays of numbers. This data is being uploaded once and being manipulated later in the GPU. we must use `Float32Array` here

Comment: I try to understand what is the purpose of your "manoever". I believe you try to batch all objects geometry into only one big vertex buffer (with corresponding indices buffer)... Am I right ?

Comment: Yes @Sedenion. I have several buffers bunch for all my objects. My objects are relatively small - I'm drawing 2d letters and geometries - with extra attributes as color, texLocs,... Saving each object in his own buffer will not be smart in my case. Some objects has more/less letters and with that the attributes amount changes of course

Comment: @Sedenion Why did you delete your answer? i wanted to get in to it now and see maybe it is solving my problems

Comment: I though my answer was not the proper one considering your question, since your question was moved out of 'webgl' section... I restored it...

Comment: I still thinks it is relevant to `webgl` developers cause it is a (i think) known problem at this area.. but i will not fight with THE gman :)

Comment: Sadly, I think you cannot do really better. The major bottleneck is that you must keep contiguous data within the vertex buffer. The linked list can "merge" your current two layers into a single, while Obj-VBOoffset relation is easy and pretty cheap to update. But the reassignation of values within the vertex buffer at deletion remain the same. My advice is to try to forgot the "map" array and implement a smart (smarter than my example) linked-list of objects, then benchmark to see if this is worst or better than your actual algorithm. I will now disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i add another answer more specific to the "indexing" problem. I precise here that I still do not visualize very well what you want to acheive... I try another answer to give you clues or ideas.

Your main problem is, if I understand, to properly follow indexing of objects depending if some within the list are deleted or added. So to say, their "coordinates" within a list.

You use a "map" array to organize in some manner your object list, which is a quite rigid structure. Because I am acustomed to C++ language, I don't know what a "map" array is, this kind of thing is an heresy for me, so I natively think without this kind of tool. So I propose to you a totaly new way to organize your objects: a linked list.

The idea is pretty simple: Instead of using a classical array, you use objects that are all linked each together. Here is how you could implement it:

```
/* this is our object constructor, it takes two 
 arguments: 
  - the previous object in the list
  - its own arbitrary uid to identify it 
*/
function MyLinkedObject(previous, uid)
{
  // our object UID
  this.uid = uid;

  // this is the reference to the previous object in the list
  this.prevObj = previous; 

  /* maybe this is the first object of the list */
  if(previous != null) {
    // we set the "next" reference of the previous object to "this"
    previous.nextObj = this;
  }

  // this object has no "nextObj" for now, it is at the end of list
  this.nextObj  = null;

  // we assume this object have a "size"
  this.size = 5;
}
```

You can now easily build your list simply using a function like this:

```
// we store our last added object every time
lastObject = new MyLinkedObject(lastObject, "Toto");
```

One of your problem is, for example to know the arbitrary offset of your object in the list, at any time, for this, nothing simpler: you implement a member function to your object that will recursively call all its predecessors:

```
MyLinkedObject.prototype.getOffset = function()
{  
   /* maybe this object is the first of the list, so 
    we verify that it have a previous object */
   if(this.prevObj != null) {
      return this.prevObj.size + this.prevObj.getOffset();
   } else {
      return 0;
   }
};
```

If you now want to be able to delete an object and keep the right offset, nothing more easy, You just have to implement a "remove" method that will unlik the object from the list:

```
MyLinkedObject.prototype.remove = function()
{
  /* maybe this is the first object of the list */
  if(this.prevObj != null) {

    // re-link previous to next
    this.prevObj.nextObj = this.nextObj;

    /* does this object have a successor ? */
    if(this.nextObj != null) {

      // re-link next to previous
      this.nextObj.prevObj = this.prevObj;
    } 

  } else { // this is the first object

    /* does this object have a successor ? */
    if(this.nextObj != null) {

      // the next object becomes the first of the list
      this.nextObj.prevObj = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Alright, now you have a dynamical structure where all object can be removed easily with offset that is naturally maintained valid and aligned. You probably now want to browse this list, for exampe, to search a particular one:

```
// assuming we stored the first object somewhere
let obj = firstObject;
while(obj != null) {
  if(obj.uid == "toto") {
    console.log("Toto found !");
    break;
  }
  obj = obj.nextObj;
}
```

Comment: "I still do not visualize very well what you want to acheive" - Maybe this is why we are not on the same page :) Your solution is solving perhaps the  re-indexing but every time i need to delete an object i need to find it in the linked-list and calculate its offset (we can do it in one run - instead of 2). The problems starts with objects in the end of the lists. finding them requires running all over the list. I will edit my post with more visual explanation of my current solution which only doing the finding part. without calculating at all. but still not happy with that

Comment: No, with linked-list, you just have to find the object, remove it, and the offset of all other objects are automatically optained using the getOffset() method of each object. Like this your list is always "up to date". I admit that in Javascript (in contrary to compiled code), browsing the linked list may be a little less efficient than finding an object with its "key" in map array, but try, you may be surprised (notice that behind the scene, the browser have to find your key-value pair in an huge array, and this is not magical, this is based on for loops...)

Comment: When I meant calculate i mean that the value is being calculate and i don't have it saved. Some run will have to be made. Regarding indexing objects, never checked it, but I really hope (and guess) that chrome/... are indexing properties objects smart and not by simple arrays.

Comment: "Smart" things at low-level are such things like "linked list" or "graphs", that allow to more or less efficiently search in a mass of linked objects without inspecting the entire list. Sometimes you have no choice, you must inspect the entire list until you found the desired value, or sadly to return "not found". Simply ask yourself: How would you implements a key-value pair array if the only thing available is a simple Array without any `find` method ? You'll may found how chrome have implemented it...